# Outputting html form data to a text file?

Tags: html

I recently created my own website using html and I wanted to add a comment section that outputted a user's comment to a text file. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: This question is unclear: did you already create a form (or use something like ajax) that captures a user's comments and now want to write this to a text file. Or do you just want to know how to capture user input and write this to a text file on capture? And what have you tried?

Comment: Im sorry for being unclear, I already have the form but I am uncertain about the output code

Comment: You need to add the code your using for your form and explain what you are using server-side to process web-requests (Rasberry Pi comes with Python, C, C++, Java, Scratch, and Ruby).

Comment: This will require some non-trivial server-side code - this is not possible using only HTML. I think based on that, this question will be too broad for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an 'action page', it's a page or script that takes the contents of your form, and does something with it.

You'll also need to use a scripting language like php, though there are many options.

This would be good a start.

http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/15.html

Then something like:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Write to a text file</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Leave a comment</h1>
<form action="myfile.php" method='post'>
<textarea name='textblock'></textarea>
<input type='submit' value='Add text'>
</form>

<?php

// Open the text file
$f = fopen("textfile.txt", "w");

// Write text
fwrite($f, $_POST["textblock"]); 

// Close the text file
fclose($f);

// Open file for reading, and read the line
$f = fopen("textfile.txt", "r");

// Read text
echo fgets($f); 
fclose($f);

?>

</body>

</html>
```